Issue with Backdrop blur on Chrome
I am trying to apply a backdrop blur on the header of my website (Made with NextJS and Tailwind). It works great on Firefox, Safari...
However, on Chrome, it is just random. sometimes, I catch it working, but then I scroll and it does not work anymore.
Firefox:
Firefox Image of Blured Header
Chrome:
Chrome Image of Blured Header
Here is my Code:
<div>
            <header
                className={`tw-flex tw-justify-between tw-items-center tw-p-4 tw-w-full md:tw-h-20 tw-font-mono tw-text-black dark:tw-text-white tw-gap-3 tw-fixed tw-z-50 ${useScrollDirection() == 'down' ? 'header-hidden' : 'header-show'}`}
            >
                <div
                    ref={menuRef}
                    className={`tw-backdrop-blur-xl md:tw-flex md:tw-h-full md:tw-justify-center md:tw-items-center tw-align-top tw-bg-[rgba(100,100,100,0.1)] dark:tw-bg-[rgba(150,150,150,0.1)] tw-grid tw-px-0 tw-py-1 tw-rounded-[20px] ${menu ? 'show-menu' : ''} ${menuIsHidden ? 'tw-hidden' : ''} menu tw-text-3xl tw-w-full md:tw-w-auto md:tw-mr-auto md:tw-ml-auto`}
                >
                    {menuItems.map((item, index) => (
                        <Link
                            key={item}
                            href={`/#${item.toLowerCase()}`}
                            onClick={menu ? () => setShowMenu(false) : () => {}}
                            className={`tw-rounded-[20px] tw-py-2 tw-px-3 md:hover:tw-bg-[rgba(50,50,50,0.1)] dark:md:hover:tw-bg-[rgba(200,200,200,0.1)] icon-click`}
                        >
                            <p className={`glitch-word md:tw-text-2xl`}>
                                {item.split('').map((char, i) => (
                                    <span key={i}>{char}</span>
                                ))}
                            </p>
                        </Link>
                    ))}
                </div>
                <div
                    className={`tw-flex tw-gap-3 tw-h-full ${icon ? '' : 'hide-icon'} ${iconIsHidden ? 'tw-hidden' : ''} header-icon tw-justify-between tw-w-full md:tw-w-auto`}
                >
                    <div className="tw-flex tw-justify-center tw-items-center md:tw-hidden tw-bg-[rgba(100,100,100,0.1)] dark:tw-bg-[rgba(150,150,150,0.1)] tw-p-3 tw-rounded-full tw-aspect-square tw-h-12 md:tw-h-full md:hover:tw-bg-[rgba(50,50,50,0.1)] dark:md:hover:tw-bg-[rgba(200,200,200,0.1)] icon-click">
                        <button
                            className=""
                            onClick={() => {
                                setShowMenu(true);
                            }}
                        >
                            <Image
                                src={!dark ? menuDarkIcon : menuLightIcon}
                                alt="menu"
                                className="menu-icon"
                            />
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="tw-flex tw-justify-center tw-items-center tw-bg-[rgba(100,100,100,0.1)] dark:tw-bg-[rgba(150,150,150,0.1)] tw-rounded-full tw-as tw-aspect-square tw-h-12 md:tw-h-full md:hover:tw-bg-[rgba(50,50,50,0.1)] dark:md:hover:tw-bg-[rgba(200,200,200,0.1)] icon-click">
                        <button
                            className="tw-p-2"
                            onClick={() => {
                                setIconRotate(true);
                                setTimeout(() => {
                                    setDark((val) => !val);
                                    setIconRotate(false);
                                }, 500);
                            }}
                        >
                            <Image
                                src={!dark ? moonIcon : sunIcon}
                                alt="toggle darkmode"
                                className={`themeIcon ${iconRotate ? 'icon-rotate' : ''}`}
                            />
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
</div>


Since this don't have anything to do with React, could you please post the rendered html instead or trim down your code to [mre]? This helps people to test your code without needing to refactor it into HTML or use a React environment with Tailwind being setup as well as guessing what the your variables' value are.

I tried to reproduce the issue in a codepen, but it didn't work.
Here is the website if that helps:
https://pascal-burri.com

Links to other websites aren't adequate, and all information should be in your question. Show us the rendered HTML, please, and not your application code.

Trying Removing this class from header: header-show (This is the one might be conflicting).
From below:
<div>
        <header
            className={`tw-flex tw-justify-between tw-items-center tw-p-4 tw-w-full md:tw-h-20 tw-font-mono tw-text-black dark:tw-text-white tw-gap-3 tw-fixed tw-z-50 ${useScrollDirection() == 'down' ? 'header-hidden' : 'header-show'}`}
        >
            <div
                ref={menuRef}
                className={`backdrop-blur-xl md:tw-flex md:tw-h-full md:tw-justify-center md:tw-items-center tw-align-top tw-bg-[rgba(100,100,100,0.1)] dark:tw-bg-[rgba(150,150,150,0.1)] tw-grid tw-px-0 tw-py-1 tw-rounded-[20px] ${menu ? 'show-menu' : ''} ${menuIsHidden ? 'tw-hidden' : ''} menu tw-text-3xl tw-w-full md:tw-w-auto md:tw-mr-auto md:tw-ml-auto`}
            >
                {menuItems.map((item, index) => (
                    <Link
                        key={item}
                        href={`/#${item.toLowerCase()}`}
                        onClick={menu ? () => setShowMenu(false) : () => {}}
                        className={`tw-rounded-[20px] tw-py-2 tw-px-3 md:hover:tw-bg-[rgba(50,50,50,0.1)] dark:md:hover:tw-bg-[rgba(200,200,200,0.1)] icon-click`}
                    >
                        <p className={`glitch-word md:tw-text-2xl`}>
                            {item.split('').map((char, i) => (
                                <span key={i}>{char}</span>
                            ))}
                        </p>
                    </Link>
                ))}
            </div>
            <div
                className={`tw-flex tw-gap-3 tw-h-full ${icon ? '' : 'hide-icon'} ${iconIsHidden ? 'tw-hidden' : ''} header-icon tw-justify-between tw-w-full md:tw-w-auto`}
            >
                <div className="tw-flex tw-justify-center tw-items-center md:tw-hidden tw-bg-[rgba(100,100,100,0.1)] dark:tw-bg-[rgba(150,150,150,0.1)] tw-p-3 tw-rounded-full tw-aspect-square tw-h-12 md:tw-h-full md:hover:tw-bg-[rgba(50,50,50,0.1)] dark:md:hover:tw-bg-[rgba(200,200,200,0.1)] icon-click">
                    <button
                        className=""
                        onClick={() => {
                            setShowMenu(true);
                        }}
                    >
                        <Image
                            src={!dark ? menuDarkIcon : menuLightIcon}
                            alt="menu"
                            className="menu-icon"
                        />
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div className="tw-flex tw-justify-center tw-items-center tw-bg-[rgba(100,100,100,0.1)] dark:tw-bg-[rgba(150,150,150,0.1)] tw-rounded-full tw-as tw-aspect-square tw-h-12 md:tw-h-full md:hover:tw-bg-[rgba(50,50,50,0.1)] dark:md:hover:tw-bg-[rgba(200,200,200,0.1)] icon-click">
                    <button
                        className="tw-p-2"
                        onClick={() => {
                            setIconRotate(true);
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                setDark((val) => !val);
                                setIconRotate(false);
                            }, 500);
                        }}
                    >
                        <Image
                            src={!dark ? moonIcon : sunIcon}
                            alt="toggle darkmode"
                            className={`themeIcon ${iconRotate ? 'icon-rotate' : ''}`}
                        />
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>


That isn't the issue, I just use tw- as prefix for my tailwind.
I tested it with native css too, and it had the same issue. however, I couldn't reproduce the issue in a code-pen.
Here is the deployed website: https://pascal-burri.com

Trying Removing this class from header: header-show (This is the one might be conflicting).

Thanks Raj, you solved it. The problem had something to do with the said class applying opacity: 1 to the header, and somehow this confused the backdrop blur. Have a nice day!
